# Is there an Excel function to work out which month in the Quarter

Tags: excel, function, vba

Is there a function in excel that helps you to work out if you're in the first, second or third month in a quarter 1,2,3?

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
=MOD(MONTH(TODAY())-1,3)+1
```

Here is an example for dates in column **A**:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

In VBA:

```
Public Function quartre(d As Date) As Integer
    Dim m As Integer
    m = Month(d)
    quartre = ((m - 1) Mod 3) + 1
End Function
```

Comment: I am creating a vba macro, would i just use the excel worksheet function to in cooperate this in